# Arrange a data set in a repeating manner from a reshaped data

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, reshape

I have reshaped the data to long. It has been sorted in ascending order based on one column (as `x2` in the below reproducible example) and I want to keep the data in a repeating manner rather than factored. Here is a sample:

```
set.seed(234)
data<-data.frame(x1=c(1:12),x2=rep(1:3,each=4),x3=runif(12,min=0,max=12))
```

And I want the format something like this:

```
   x1 x2       x3
1   1  1 6.115445
2   2  2 5.157014
3   3  3 4.793458
4   4  1 9.998710
5   5  2 2.620250
6   6  3 1.825839
7   7  1 5.842854
8   8  2 5.616670
9   9  3 6.511315
10 10  1 9.164444
11 11  2 8.401418
```

Can you please help me with either what to include in the `melt` function while converting the data to long format or any other function I should use in rearranging that data.

*note*:
The above result is to show the desired format, not the exact solution for my data.

EDIT: 
Here is `head()` of my real data:

```
       Date stn Elev  Amount
1 2010-01-01  11    0 268.945
2 2010-01-01  11    0 268.396
3 2010-01-01  11    0 267.512
4 2010-01-01  11    0 266.488
5 2010-01-01  11    0 265.558
6 2010-01-01  11    0 265.178
```

In the actual data, the column `Elev` contains values like, `c("0","100","250","500"...)`. So you assume that `0` is equivalent to `1` in `x2` of the above sample, and so forth for `100`, `250`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use `ave` as follows:

```
data[order(ave(data$x3, data$x2, FUN=function(i) 1:length(i)), data$x2),]
   x1 x2         x3
1   1  1  8.9474400
5   5  2  0.8029211
9   9  3 11.1328381
2   2  1  9.3805491
6   6  2  7.7375415
10 10  3  3.4107614
3   3  1  0.2404454
7   7  2 11.1526315
11 11  3  6.6686992
4   4  1  9.3130246
8   8  2  8.6117063
12 12  3  6.5724198
```

In this instance, `ave` calculates a running count by data$x2, which is then used to sort the data with the `order` function.

You can also renumber x1 if desired: `data$x1 <- 1:nrow(data)`, which would return your desired result.

Comment: @G1124E better to add this to your question. It's not all that readable as a comment.

Comment: Your Date variable was read in as a factor. You should use the as.is=TRUE argument in `read.csv` or `read.table`. This will assure that variables are either numeric or character. Also, use stn as the first entry to `ave` rather than Date.

Comment: @Imo Yes, your last comment worked. Thank you very much.